# Which is faster - map chars or for loop?

Tags: rust

Which of these is more efficient?

```
        /* Approach 1  */

        //Calculate GC NUM
        let gc_count: i32 = line
            .chars()
            .map(|c| match c {
                'A' | 'T' => 0,
                'C' | 'G' => 1,
                _ => 0,
            })
            .sum();

        // Calculate NT NUM
        let total = line.chars().count();
```

```
        /* Approach 2 */

        // Calculate GC NUM
        // Calculate NT NUM
        for c in line.chars(){
            if c == 'G' || c == 'C' {
                gc_count += 1;
                total += 1;
            }
            else {
                total += 1;
            }
```

I assume iterating through chars twice is slower than once - however not sure how for loop compares to something like map.

Comment: Why won't you benchmark?

Comment: `for` loop and `map()` should be equivalent.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The `map` approach is iterating twice (the second time to obtain `total`) but that can also be trivially solved by using `fold` instead, which would indeed emit equivalent code.

Comment: You could do the `total` addition in conjunction with either your `map` or `for` trivially: `total += match c { ... }`.

Comment: I would bet on map and sum because iterators implement some optimizations for cases when they are aggregated while for loops are always iterate them useing consequitive `Iterator::next`. For example, `chars().count()` use `count_chars` call https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/str/iter.rs.html#48

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros This should not matter on `chars()` (only on iterators like `chain()`), and I don't think this will have the same impact as iterating once instead of twice.

Comment: @cdhowie I'm well aware, I talked about the general case of `for` vs. `map()`+`sum()`.

Comment: Does the compiler optimize map differently than a for loop?

Answer (score 2):

I decided to run benchmark for different variants.

I checked 2 your variants + 2 my variants: with domain data knowledge and single fold.

From your code, I assumed that you do some kind of gencode processing. So it is possible to assume that your data mainly contains from ASCII chars. Knowing that you look for ASCII characters and knowing that UTF-8 encoding guarantees that bytes that contains ASCII code is an ASCII symbol (see [endoding details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding)), I count 'G' and 'C' occurences iterating over *bytes* slice instead of chars. I also use ASCII-based total length checking because it is likely that string would be ASCII. This approach called "Data knowledge" in my benchmark and it is proven to be fastest for my mock data.

Second approach using fold. I added it to check how would single iteration work compared to 2 iterations from your `map` example. It happened to be third by speed.

In your place, I would myself use double iteration using `s.chars().filter(|&x|x=='G' || x == 'C').count()` and `s.chars().count()` because it is most simple and obvious code and it is not much slower than most optimized variant.

For loop proven to be slowest, as I expected.

```rust
// Results:
// GC/Double chars iteration time:   [111.98 µs 112.17 µs 112.38 µs]
// GC/For loop iteration     time:   [782.77 µs 783.52 µs 784.39 µs]
// GC/Data knowledge         time:   [97.609 µs 97.826 µs 98.070 µs]
// GC/Fold                   time:   [126.01 µs 126.16 µs 126.32 µs]

const GENOM_SIZE: usize = 100_000;

fn generate_genom(rng: &mut impl Rng) -> String {
    (0..GENOM_SIZE)
        .map(|_| *['A', 'C', 'G', 'T'].choose(rng).unwrap())
        .collect()
}

fn count_using_chars(s: &str) -> (usize, usize) {
    let gc_count: usize = s
        .chars()
        .map(|c| match c {
            'A' | 'T' => 0,
            'C' | 'G' => 1,
            _ => 0,
        })
        .sum();
    let total = s.chars().count();
    (total, gc_count)
}

fn count_using_loop(s: &str) -> (usize, usize) {
    let mut total = 0;
    let mut gc_count = 0;

    for c in s.chars() {
        if c == 'G' || c == 'C' {
            gc_count += 1;
        }
        total += 1;
    }

    (total, gc_count)
}

fn count_using_data_knowledge(s: &str) -> (usize, usize) {
    let gc_count = s
        .as_bytes()
        .iter()
        .copied()
        // Here I exploit the fact that we search ASCII symbols
        // and any ASCII symbol is guaranteed to be represented as such in UTF-8.
        // Also I use `binary or` to remove extra branch.
        .filter(|&x| (x == b'G') | (x == b'C'))
        .count();
    // Since our string is genom string,
    // it is very likely ASCII string.
    // So I exploit this knowledge to count chars even faster.
    let total = if s.is_ascii() {
        s.len()
    } else {
        s.chars().count()
    };
    (total, gc_count)
}

fn count_using_fold(s: &str) -> (usize, usize) {
    s.chars()
        .fold((0, 0), |(total, mut gc_count), ch|{
            if ch == 'G' || ch == 'C' {
                gc_count += 1;
            }
            (total + 1, gc_count)
        })
}

fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let mut group = c.benchmark_group("GC");

    group.bench_function("Double chars iteration", |b| {
        let mut rng = StdRng::seed_from_u64(1000);
        b.iter_batched(
            move || generate_genom(&mut rng),
            |genom| {
                let r = count_using_chars(&genom);
                (genom, r)
            },
            BatchSize::SmallInput,
        );
    });

    group.bench_function("For loop iteration", |b| {
        let mut rng = StdRng::seed_from_u64(1000);
        b.iter_batched(
            move || generate_genom(&mut rng),
            |genom| {
                let r = count_using_loop(&genom);
                (genom, r)
            },
            BatchSize::SmallInput,
        );
    });

    group.bench_function("Data knowledge", |b| {
        let mut rng = StdRng::seed_from_u64(1000);
        b.iter_batched(
            move || generate_genom(&mut rng),
            |genom| {
                let r = count_using_data_knowledge(&genom);
                (genom, r)
            },
            BatchSize::SmallInput,
        );
    });

    group.bench_function("Fold", |b| {
        let mut rng = StdRng::seed_from_u64(1000);
        b.iter_batched(
            move || generate_genom(&mut rng),
            |genom| {
                let r = count_using_fold(&genom);
                (genom, r)
            },
            BatchSize::SmallInput,
        );
    });

    group.finish();
}
```

Comment: Very comprehensive, thank you. So why is double iteration faster than a for loop?

Comment: @MladenRasic I think, there is 2 main reasons: 1. there is special optimization for `chars().count()`, 2. probably, loop which does less things inside can be better optimized by compiler. I am not sure though.